# Disabling the accordion effect in the Palette window in App Inventor 2's designer

Tags: app-inventor

Is there any way to disable the accordion effect in the Palette window in App Inventor 2's designer? I'd like to leave both the "user interface" and the "layout" sub-menus open.

[image]

Comment: You can write a user script for Tampermonkey browser plugin, which will modify the AI web page and will show all sub menus.

Comment: @MirecXP Thanks, I was hoping for some settings in AI2, but I guess the only solution is amending the page's source code indeed (or contributing to AI2 code).

Comment: no you can't, but if you take a look at the [Components Documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/), you can see the description of all components easily... also the [Language Blocks Documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks.html) might be interesting for you... see also the [library](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/library)...

Comment: Feel free to cast comments as an answer.